# Puppet: Service must be down to change config files

Tags: puppet

I have an issue with puppet.

I need to define a service with *"ensure=>running"* but its config files can only be changed while the service is stopped. The default behaviour seems to be that the service is restarted after config files changed (connected through *notify*).

Is this representable with puppet? And if so, how?

Regards Jan

Comment: Of course you could do it with an exec, but that isn't really the  preferred way.

Comment: @Zoredache : I thought about that too. But there should be a _preferred way_, shouldn't it?

Comment: Not really this seems pretty uncommon. Most services simply parse and read the config file when they are starting.  Changing the configuration file while running doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Zoredache: I need this for JBoss. It frequently rewrites its config file because some runtime information is stored in that file as well.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/882811/puppet-stop-service-before-overwriting-file/882898#882898

Answer (score 5):

Here is an ugly method with an exec.  There may be better solutions.

```
# push file system, but don't replace 'real' config file
file { '/etc/service/config.staging':
  ensure => present,
  source => 'puppet:///modules/service/config',
  notify => Exec['reload-service']
}

# stop service, update config, start service
exec { 'reload-service':
  command => '/etc/init.d/service stop; cp /etc/service/config.staging /etc/service/config; /etc/init.d/service start',
  refreshonly => true,
  path => ["/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin/"],
  logoutput => false,
}
```

Comment: That's not ugly at all, I think it's quite elegant.