# puppet: stop service before overwriting file

Tags: puppet

I got the following simplified configuration:

```
file {
  '/etc/foo.conf':
    ensure  => file,
    content => epp('my_module/etc/foo.conf.epp'),
  ;
}

service {
  'foo':
    ensure    => running,
    enable    => true,
    subscribe => File['/etc/foo.conf'],
  ;
}
```

When i update the template, puppet overwrite `/etc/foo.conf` then restart the service.

My problem is that i need to stop the service **before** overwriting the file because when the service is stopping it write back the configuration it has in memory to the file.

Is there a way to do it with puppet ?

Comment: I am curious to know why you mean with the configuration is write back? can you tell the name of the service?

Comment: @c4f4t0r it is the deluged bittorent client. i don't know precisely what it is doing but i just observed that it overwrite its configuration file when stopping. so puppet overwrite must occurs only when service is not running if not with a restart it will never had the new configuration

Comment: You can do it with an exec before the file, but then you have the service stopping and starting on every Puppet run. I can't think of a way to do it only when the file needs to be modified. The best way I can think of, and this sounds *insane*, is to write a provider for the file resource that does what you need it to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [transition module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-transition). With that, you can do something like this:

```
transition { 'stop foo service':
  resource   => Service['foo'],
  attributes => { ensure => stopped },
  prior_to   => File['/etc/foo.conf'],
}

file { '/etc/foo.conf':
  ensure  => file,
  content => epp('my_module/etc/foo.conf.epp'),
}

service { 'foo':
  ensure    => running,
  enable    => true,
  subscribe => File['/etc/foo.conf'],
}
```

No `exec`'s required.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
file { '/etc/foo.conf.tmp':
  ensure  => file,
  content => epp('my_module/etc/foo.conf.epp'),
}

exec { 'stop service':
  command => 'service foo stop',
  refreshonly => true,
  subscribe => File['/etc/foo.conf.tmp']
}

exec { 'update file':
  command => 'cp /etc/foo.conf.tmp /etc/foo.conf',
  subscribe => Exec['stop service'],
  refreshonly => true,
}

exec { 'start service':
  command => 'service foo start',
  subscribe => Exec['update file'],
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

The `refreshonly` attribute of the `exec` resource will ensure the command is only run when it received an event, in this case via the `subscribe` attribute. In this case, it will only stop the server and copy in the new settings file when your tmp settings file is changed. The tmp file will allow you to manage the your settings on the server without the service overwriting it.

You could combine those three `exec`s into a single command like so

```
file { '/etc/foo.conf.tmp':
  ensure  => file,
  content => epp('my_module/etc/foo.conf.epp'),
}

exec { 'update settings':
  command => 'service foo stop && cp /etc/foo.conf.tmp /etc/foo.conf && service foo start',
  refreshonly => true,
  subscribe => File['/etc/foo.conf.tmp']
}
```

Comment: Clever solution!